# How to import third party templates into Webmatrix?

Tags: templates, web, webmatrix

Is it possible to import third-party website templates (like templates from templatemonster) into Webmatrix? I already have a site in officelive and I want to move my site from there; can I import template from offivelive website into Webmatrix? If it is possible please let me know how it can be done, I am a total newbie in Webmatrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just purchase a template from template monster. They will provide you with a link. Go to your site settings (NeGet repositories). Hit add new repository and enter the link that is given to you. After that switch to that repository and install the template. Thats about it.

Comment: Where does this repository exists in Webmatrix? I am not sure about it. Does it work for other templates in zip file?

Comment: Open http://localhost:59000/_Admin or whatever port you are using. On top right of the page hit Manage Package Resources. Add the template url as a source and give it a name. Save it. Return to the previous page. You new source should appear on the drop down. Choose it and install the package. This should be it.

Comment: One side note. You should select Razor Templates from templatemonster if you want to install it this way. Right now only those are supported. If you have other templates you have to manually install them by hacking and slashing :)